# jsf managed beans netbeans 13 not found in file wizard

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans-13

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evy7t.png)Java student here. I'm creating my first JSF project. I'm using NetBeans13 and following along with the textbook and oracle. I can't move forward since I can't find the location of JSF managed beans. I've emailed my professor and waiting for a response but in the meantime, I thought I would write my first stack overflow question. I've googled as well but I can't find anyone else that has encountered this problem. I've also restarted netbeans. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the CDI bean

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: CDI bean worked